# UISearchBarController not hide after returned button called

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uikeyboard

I have a viewController with a tableViewController inside.
My problem is that the SearchBar does not disappear when I press the return button so what does it when I press the cancel button.
Have you an idea of the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use an UISearchDisplayController, try this

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

when you call the action make by return button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dismiss the search interface (like search bar and "cancel" button). The next code does it:

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out !

I simply used an UISearchBar with controller !